# SPList returns no result if CAML query is modified or removed

Tags: list, powershell, caml

I have a `SharePoint` `PowerShell` script which gets items from a list.

I am changing the `CAML` query for different output.

However, upon changing or removing the `CAML` query, the method of `list.GetItems()` returned `0` result and I have no clue why it is so.

Below is my code snippet:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set config variables
$baseUrl="http://test.com/"
$listName ="Lists/FilePlan"

#Get Web and List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listName)

#Define the CAML Query
$queryOriginal = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$queryOriginal.Query = "@
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Folder Content Type</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>"

$queryModified = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$queryModified.Query = "@
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Document Content Type</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>"

#Get List Items matching the query
$items = $list.GetItems($queryOriginal)  //result
$items2 = $list.GetItems($queryModified) //zero result*****
$items3 = $list.GetItems()               //zero result*****
```

---

**Edit:**

Tried using `<Neq>` but to no avail as well.

Comment: what is document library name

Comment: What CAML have you tried?